# Is it possible to compare a datetime.date value in if-else statement?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, datetime

I would like to compare a datetime.date value in a dictionary with an if-else statement. However, I am unsure of which string to compare.

```
dict = {'monday': datetime.date(2021, 8, 7)}
day_input = input('Enter day: ')
```

The output for the values in the dictionary is 2021-08-07.
Do I use '2021-08-07' or '2021, 8, 7'? I've tried both methods and both prints no when it should be Yes.

```
  if dict[day_input] == '2021, 8, 7':
      print('Yes')
  else: 
      print('No')
```

Comment: `if dict[day_input] == datetime.date(2021, 8, 7)`…

Comment: this doesnt work because the datetime.date is not defined

Comment: Wut?! You're using it two lines earlier…!

Comment: i think its because the dictonary was retrieved from the dataframe. The values in the column are the dates in datetime format.

Comment: That hardly explains why you can't use `datetime.date`. Perhaps you simply need to `import datetime`…?

Comment: Oh lol, that was the issue. Thanks for your help! Sorry for such a simple question

Comment: also, dont name variables like `dict`

Answer (score 0):

That is not supposed to be a string. Just do the  `if dict[day_input] == datetime.date(2021, 8, 7)`